# Best way to add "dynamic" controls?

Tags: c#

My program will prompt the user for a number, i.e. 25. The program will then start the "main form" with 25 controls (textbox). The 25 (or whatever number) of textboxes (or whatever control) will need to be formatted evenly. I will also need to be able to retrieve the text (or another property if I use another control) in order, from left to right and up to down. What is the best method of approaching this?

Comment: If you can use WPF, start over and use templates/MVVM. Thats the *best* method.

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail? Is it possible for WPF to be cross platform? Mainly OSX?

Comment: In WinForms add a TablelayooutPanel with required rows as per user input and add textbox inside each row.

Answer (score 2):

Using WPF MVVM. In a `.XAML` file, create a `DataTemplate` with the `DataType` of a ViewModel that will provide the binding for your `TextBox`s, lets call this the `TextboxViewModel`. Then using a `ItemsControl` element with an `ItemsSource` of `TextboxViewModel`. You'll be able to instantiate as many `TextBox`s as you want and be able to get the result by browsing through your list of `TextboxViewModel`.

Comment: Would it be possible to port WPF to OSX?

Comment: Microsoft opened up their platform to other OS this year but I would say it's a bit early to start programming in C# for OSX. You should use another toolkit such as the ones targetted to OSX or using a cross platform famework such as QT.

Comment: WPF has not been supported by Mono, and is not readily available for OSX. see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/

Comment: My main target audience is still Windows. Support for OSX would just be a nice convenience.

Comment: Without support for WPF, you could still use Winform (and therefore the solution proposed by @Mihai Caracostea). But it's easy to sink a lot of time making a cross platform software running on a platform specific framework. So be sure to understand all the implications.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are using Windows Forms here.
Dynamically create the X controls and add them to the Controls collection of your form. To ease the access to them you can store their reference in a List and set some event handlers too, depending on your needs. You just need to calculate their positions while you add them.

Answer (score 0):

If WinForms, this is exactly what the [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for.  Just add the controls to it and they will arrange themselves automatically, wrapping down to the next row as needed.  As Mihai already suggested, you could also keep reference to those controls in a List.

Another option would be to use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It's a little more difficult to learn and use, but is much more flexible and powerful.